# how to separate names with space in sql server with php and update them separately in different rows

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a large database which has only a single row for customers name. Now we have added three more rows(First_name, Last_name and Middle_name). We are trying to get the customers name and seperate them respectively into individual column.

Here is a scenerio of what i mean:

Main table

```
       Name       
__________________
Fagbemi Ayodele O
```

Expected table

```
     First_name  |  Last_name | Middle_name 
   ___________________________________________
       Fagbemi      |  Ayodele   |  O
```

And some of the names are like this:

OKPARA ISSAC.N
ROSEMARY O. IGBO
Akpaowo Uduaka U.J.
Agu  - Ifeji - Helen

How can i filter them and separate them?

```
      Name       |    First_name  |  Last_name 
________________________________________________
Gbenga James      |  Fagbemi       |  Ayodele
```

Comment: Unless you're actually prompting the user to enter separate values into separate form fields, it is simply not possible to do this accurately. It will ***never*** be 100% correct. Save yourself the trouble and leave name as a single field. There is rarely a legitimate business case to need to know the difference.

Comment: $nameParts = explode(" ", $name); if(count($nameParts) == 2){ $firstName = $nameParts[0]; $lastName = $nameParts[1]; } else if($nameParts >= 3){.... etc, you will have to also filter out "Mr, Mrs, Ms" and all of those... and "Jr. Sr." etc if you want. I recommend using something like that if you really want to do it... but it will never be 100% accurate... Mr. Johnny Smith Wilkinson Jr for example is a "5 part name"

Comment: And things like "Wilkinson, Johnny Smith" make parsing names like this nearly impossible. Then you get into the double last names and all sorts of other name things that you would likely never think about. Also I think this is a good time to drop this article into the discussion. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate your comments and time.